# Linear Regression with 3x3 Matrices

Tags: matrices, regression

Here's my Homework Problem:

> We can generalize the least squares method to other polynomial curves. To find the quadratic equation $y=a x^2+b x+c$ that best fits the points $(-1, −3)$, $(0, 0)$, $(1, −1)$, and $(2, 1)$, we first write the matrix equation $AX=B$ that would result if a quadratic equation satisfied by all four points did indeed exist. (The third equation in this system would correspond to $x=1$ and $y= −1$: $a+b+c = −1$.) We proceed by writing the normal system $A^T A X=A^T B$.
>
> Use elementary row operations to find the equation of the quadratic equation that best fits the given four points. 
>   Enter the (exact) value of y(1) on the quadratic regression curve.

So far I have a solvable matrix using $A^T A = A^T B$

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
18 & 8 & 6 \\
 8 & 6 & 2 \\
6 & 2 & 4
\end{array}
\right)

\left(
\begin{matrix}
a \\ b \\ c
\end{matrix}
\right)

=

\left(
\begin{array}{r}
6 \\ 4 \\ -3
\end{array}
\right)

$$

Normally,

$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
a & b \\ c & d
\end{matrix}
\right)^{-1}

=

\frac{1}{a d - b c}
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
d & -b \\ -c & a
\end{array}
\right) \> .
$$

How does this law translate from $2 \times 2$ matrices to $3 \times 3$?

Comment: Note that you don't have to compute the inverse to solve the system. You can use row reduction instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "translation" is given through the use of the adjugate matrix (Cramer's Rule); you can see the result in [Wikipedia's page on matrix inverses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_inverse#Inversion_of_3.C3.973_matrices).

But it's simpler to find the inverse using elementary row operations: put your matrix on the left and the identity on the right, and row reduce until the left side is the identity; what you have on the right will be the inverse:
$$\begin{align*}
\left(\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
18 & 8 & 6 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
8 & 6 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
6 & 2 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right) &\to \left(\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
0 & 2 & -6 & 1 & 0 & -3\\
8 & 6 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
6 & 2 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right) \\
&\to\left(\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
0 & 2& -6 & 1 & 0 & -3\\
2 & 4 & -2 & 0 & 1 & -1\\
6 & 2 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)\\
&\to \left(\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
0 & 2& -6 & 1 & 0 & -3\\
2 & 4 & -2 & 0 & 1 & -1\\
0 & -10 & 10 & 0 & -3 & 4
\end{array}\right) \\
&\to \left(\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
0 & 10 & -30 & 5 & 0 & -15\\
2 & 4 & -2 & 0 & 1 & -1\\
0 & -10 & 10 & 0 & -3 & -4
\end{array}\right)\\
&\to\left(\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
0 & 0 & -20 & 5 & -3 & -11\\
2 & 4 & -2 & 0 & 1 & -1\\
0 & -10 & 10 & 0 & -3 & 4
\end{array}\right) \\
&\to \left(\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
2 & 4 & -2 & 0 & 1 & -1\\
0 & -10 & 10 & 0 & -3 & 4\\
0 & 0 & -20 & 5 & -3 & -11
\end{array}\right)\\
&\to\left(\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
20 & 40 & -20 & 0 & 10 & -10\\
0 & -20 & 20 & 0 & -6 & 8\\
0 & 0 & -20 & 5 & -3 & -11
\end{array}\right) \\
&\to
\left(\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
20 & 40 & 0 & -5 & 13 & 1\\
0 & -20 & 0 & 5 & -9 & -3\\
0 & 0 & -20 & 5 & -3 & -11
\end{array}\right)\\
&\to\left(\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
20 & 0 & 0 & 5 & -5 & -5\\
0 & -20 & 0 & 5 & -9 & -3\\
0 & 0 & -20 & 5 & -3 & -11
\end{array}\right) \\
&\to\left(\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & -\frac{1}{4} & -\frac{1}{4}\\
0 & 1 & 0 & -\frac{1}{4} & \frac{9}{20} & \frac{3}{20}\\
0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{4} & \frac{3}{20} & \frac{11}{20}
\end{array}\right)\end{align*}$$
So the inverse of your matrix is
$$\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
\frac{1}{4} & -\frac{1}{4} & -\frac{1}{4}\\
-\frac{1}{4} & \frac{9}{20} & \frac{3}{20}\\
-\frac{1}{4} & \frac{3}{20} & \frac{11}{20}
\end{array}\right).$$

Comment: @Ocasta: Notwithstanding Arturo's great answer, indulge me a reminder that the method of "normal equations" isn't always the best way to solve a least squares problem (it is certainly the most convenient way, though). You will probably be learning about the "better ways" in future courses.

Comment: @ Arturo: Excellent, thank you. The problem with relying on short cuts is its easy to forget the basic theory behind it. I'm sure I'll see something like this on my final.

Comment: @ J.M.: We learned two other techniques. One using multi variable calculus where you use first partial to minimize the sum of the squares. The other using summation of x^2, x, n, xy, and y. But my professor specifically asked for this problem to be solved using the Matrix method.